# AngularJS run function after scope is loaded

Tags: angularjs

I have one form, that should be submitted with everage POST, without ajax. Just after it's rendering.

As it is an exclusion, I decided to use some jquery inside controller.

So my form:

```
<form name="Form" id="externalForm" action="{{form.url}}" method="POST" ng-controller="ExternalFormCtrl">
    <input type="hidden" name="{{k}}" value="{{v}}" ng-repeat="(k, v) in form.form">
</form>
```

Amd my controller

```
app.controller('ExternalFormCtrl', ["$scope", "DataTransfer", function ($scope, DataTransfer) {

    $scope.form = DataTransfer.get();

    $('#externalForm').submit();


}]);
```

In DataTransfer I receive form with fields I need to send to external resource.
When it will render template, I want immidiatelly submit form with jquery.

1. How to submit form after rendering my form?
2. How to solve this task more ellegant, with angular way?

UPD: DataTransfer factory

```
app.factory('DataTransfer', [function() {
    var savedData = {}
     function set(data) {
       savedData = data;
     }
     function get() {
      return savedData;
     }

     return {
      set: set,
      get: get
     }
}]);
```

Comment: can't you just submit the values in a simple $http.post()?

Comment: You shouldn't in fact mess angular with jquery directly via calling jquery inside controller. Use directives if you need jquery integration.

Comment: Why is that @MichałKędrzyński?

Comment: As I said - I need post form without ajax. And I need to submit it automatically

Comment: Don`t mix angular code & JQuery

Comment: Could you give me good solution? I know that it's bad to mix jquery with angular

Comment: Angular is all about separating views from your application logic (MVVM / MVC patterns). When you call jquery from within your application logic, you lose all the goodness angular gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use vanilla javascript

```
document.getElementById('externalForm').submit();
```

Comment: Nice! But what to do with submiting after rendering? Now I use $timeout. But I suppose it's not very cool.

Comment: Can you show the code of the `DataTransfer.get()` method?

Comment: Updated post with DataTransfer factory

Comment: At the moment your `DataTransfer.get()` command returns immediately and hence your call to submit will be executed after that has returned and updated the values in the form so you should be ok to run it as it is without  `$timeout`

Comment: Ok, thanx! I will try!